# Python - read file, than convert string to integers

Tags: python, string, integer

I was wondering if anyone knew how to read a file and turn the ouptputed code into integers rather than string. I have been experiencing several different errors the current one being "TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer". I have done several searches for information without any results. This is my code:

```
additionalBonusRates = open("additionalBonusRates.txt", 'r')
            global kluger_additional      
            kluger_additional = additionalBonusRates.readline('\n')
            global patrol_additional
            patrol_additional = additionalBonusRates.readline('\n')
            global territory_additional
            territory_additional = additionalBonusRates.readline('\n')
            additionalBonusRates.close()
            kluger_additional = int(kluger_additional)
            patrol_additional = int(patrol_additional)
            territory_additional = int(territory_additional)
```

Comment: how does your file look like please share it. so that it will be easy to me to understand

Comment: @SundarNataraj "ur" and "pls" are not words.

Comment: Since when `file.readline` started accepting a string argument?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough rep to comment, but your error is coming from passing a string argument to [`readline()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readline)

Also, why all the globals? Do you really need that? It is typically frowned upon to declare things global like that if it isn't totally necessary.

For processing numeric data files I would also recommend you take a look at numpy

Answer (score 1):

There's no `readint` function in file objects.
What you are doing is a classic deserialization of data, using your own file format.

I don't know if you are using Python 2.7 or 3.4, but keep in mind that a File Object read raw strings, i.e. an array of bytes.

The way you do it is the right way, but I would suggest some improvements:

- Please, avoid using global variables: it confuse the programmer/maintainer.
- Use `with` statements to open the file and close it correctly.
- You can encapsulate the deserialization in a function to mask the `string` to `int` conversion.
- Try to follow the PEP8 recommandation and avoid long names where possible.

Here is an example:

```
def read_add_bonus_rates(txt_path):
    with open(txt_path, 'r') as txt_file:
        kluger_add = int(txt_file.readline())
        patrol_add = int(txt_file.readline())
        territory_add = int(txt_file.readline())
    return (kluger_add, patrol_add, territory_add)

def main():
    rates = """\
    150
    160
    180
    """
    with open('rates.txt', 'w') as rates_file:
        rates_file.write(rates)
    print(repr(read_add_bonus_rates('rates.txt')))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I don't think [PEP-8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says something about the length of a name.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using python3.  The error you are getting is not from converting your strings to integers, but from passing '\n' to the readline([n]) call.  The optional argument [n] is the maximum size to read.  You should use "rstrip" to get rid of the carriage returns conversion to int:

```
kluger_additional = int(additionalBonsuRates.readline().rstrip())
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be an empty line and thus the error.
Please try the below code, it may be helpful?

```
        additionalBonusRates = open("additionalBonusRates.txt", 'r')
        global kluger_additional      
        kluger_additional = additionalBonusRates.readline('\n').strip()

        if kluged_additional: # only go on if the line was not blank
            kluger_additionalINT = int(kluger_additional)
```